# How to replace nested stack with other component in react-native-navigation v2?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm trying to build a dynamic wizard with react-native-navigation v2.
I say dynamic because the number of steps may vary depending on which options the user selects.

I was thinking to use nested stacks, so the layout of my app would look something like this:

```js
{
  root: {
    sideMenu: {
      left: {/*...*/},
      center: {
        stack: {
          children: [component1, /*...,*/ componentX]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ComponentX is where I start my wizard, so I push a new stack like this:

```js
{
// ...
  stack: {
    children: [
      component1,
      //...,
      componentX,
      {
        stack: {
          children: [step1, step2, /*...,*/ stepN]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After the user make the last choice on stepN, I would like to replace the nested stack with a summary screen to have something like:

```js
{
//...
  stack: {
    children: [
      component1,
      //...,
      componentX,
      summaryScreen
    ]
  }
}
```

I could use `Navigation.setRoot` to reset the whole thing but that means I would probably have to store the navigation in Redux.
I've also tried using `Navigation.setStackRoot` but I'm under the impression that it's setting the parent stack root and not my nested stack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve it.
Here's how:

1. At the start of my app, when I give an id to my main stack

```js
const sideMenu = {
    left: { /*...*/ },
    center: {
      stack: {
        id: 'main', // this line is important
        children: [/*...*/]
      }
    },
  };
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: { sideMenu },
  });
```

2. When I want to start my wizard, I push a new stack

```js
Navigation.push(componentId, {
  stack: {
    id: 'wizard',
    children: [
      {
        component: { /*...*/ },
      },
    ],
  }
})
```

3. I push the screens on the new stack `wizard` as the user progresses
4. When I want to display the final summary screen, I call setStackRoot on the nested stack

```js
Navigation.setStackRoot('wizard', [
  {
    component: { /*...*/ },
  },
]);
```

5. On that summary screen, I have a button labelled 'Finish' which removes the nested stack

```js
Navigation.pop('main');
```

**EDIT:** with this approach alone, if you click on the back arrow when you are on a nested screen, it will dismiss the entire nested stack instead of this screen only.
I had to use a custom back button as follows:

I solved it by using a custom back button:
1. When pushing a new screen where I want to override the button, use the options

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
/* ... */
const backIcon = await Icon.getImageSource('arrow-back', 24, '#000');
const component = {
  id: screenID,
  name: screenID,
  passProps,
  options: {
    topBar: {
      leftButtons: [
        {
          id: 'backButton',
          icon: backIcon,
        },
      ],
    },
  }
};
return Navigation.push(componentId, { component });
```

2. Create a HOC to implement you custom back action

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

const getDisplayName = WrappedComponent => WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';

export default function withCustomBackButton(WrappedComponent) {
  class WithCustomBackButton extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      if (this.navigationEventListener) this.navigationEventListener.remove();
    }

    navigationButtonPressed() {
      // Your custom action
      const { componentId } = this.props;
      Navigation.pop(componentId);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  WithCustomBackButton.displayName = `WithCustomBackButton(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;

  return WithCustomBackButton;
}
```

3. When registering the screen with the custom back button, wrap it in your HOC

```js
import withCustomBackButton from '../components/hoc/WithCustomBackButton';
/* ... */
Navigation.registerComponent('selectLocation', () => withCustomBackButton(SelectLocation));
```

Comment: Hi @Gpack, I need a help regrading multiple stack. In my app there the 1000+ components and sub components. How to set divide the stack in my project. I am very confuse how to approach the routing. Please help me.

Comment: Hi @HarleenKaurArora, I'm far from being an expert.Here's a [link](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/why-react-developers-should-modularize-their-applications-d26d381854c1) which you may find useful to organize your app